# Java: resultSet.getTimestamp loses time

Tags: java, mysql, time, resultset

I have the following entry in my database:

```
Start                   End
2013-08-25 14:23:20     2013-09-14 14:23:20
```

(type is datetime, database is MySQL)

And in my java application I want to set this date and time to a calendar as followed:

```
java.sql.Timestamp timeStampStart = inResults.getTimestamp("start");
System.out.println("Start: " + timeStampStart);
Calendar start = new GregorianCalendar();
start.setTime(timeStampStart);
```

Edit:

added System.out.println to the code:

```
Start: 2013-08-25 15:11:08.0
End: 2013-09-14 15:11:08.0 (same code as for start)
```

Now the thing is, the time is lost when I call inResults.getTimestamp. I get the correct date, but the time is the time the queried is executed instead of the time in the database.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure it's the `getTimestamp()` and not the `Calendar.setTime()`? What do you see when you add a `System.out.println(timestampStart.toString());`

Comment: Added extra System.out.println in post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No argument constructor

> Constructs a default GregorianCalendar using the current time in the default time zone with the default locale.

You can create java.util.Date from your Timestamp then getHours(), getMinutes(), and getSeconds() from the Date and use it in Calendar's constructor. signature is below.

```
GregorianCalendar(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second)
```

something like this:

```
    java.sql.Timestamp timeStampStart = inResults.getTimestamp("start"); 
    java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date(timeStampStart.getTime());
    Calendar start = new GregorianCalendar(d.getYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), d.getHours(), d.getMminutes(), d.getSeconds());
```